# jquery show more/less having issue with added html tags

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with HTML Tags inside the comment div, more text link is not showing up when I insert `<p>something</p>` tag.  It works fine with plain text. I want to insert rich text, and it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<H2>
    Dynamically shortened Text with Show More link using jQuery
</H2>
</div>
<p>Click here to view the Tutorial: <a href="http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/12/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery.html">Shortened Text with Show More link</a></p>

<br/>
<div class="comment more">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
    quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
    Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
    blandit id luctus felis convallis.
    Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
    Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.</p>
</div>
<div class="comment more">
    Duis nisl nibh, egestas at fermentum at, viverra et purus.
    Maecenas lobortis odio id sapien facilisis elementum.
    Curabitur et magna justo, et gravida augue.
    Sed tristique pellentesque arcu quis tempor.
</div>
<div class="comment more">
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin blandit nunc sed sem dictum id feugiat quam blandit.
    Donec nec sem sed arcu interdum commodo ac ac diam. Donec consequat semper rutrum.
    Vestibulum et mauris elit. Vestibulum mauris lacus, ultricies.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, input{
    font-family: Calibri, Arial;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
a {
    color: #0254EB
}
a:visited {
    color: #0254EB
}
#header h2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #00A1E6;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.comment {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px;
}
a.morelink {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
    display: none;

}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Skdmk/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is because you are taking `var content = $(this).html();`. The html has a `<p>` and when you take the `substr` you end up with malformed html. Different browsers will handle the malformed html differently. Your `morelink` link gets put outside of the `<p>` and toggle ends up hiding it. Use `var content = $(this).text();` instead or find a plugin that will handle this better.

Comment: @Danny that seems like it's worth posting as a full answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: I changed the fiddle. It is working in the sense it is showing more or less, but I added line break, list etc, They are all flat, comming side by side without any line gap. Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Skdmk/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are taking `var content = $(this).html();`. The html has a `<p>` and when you take the substr you end up with malformed html with no closing tag (ex. `<p>Some Text`). Different browsers will handle the malformed html differently. Your `morelink` link gets put outside of the `<p>` and toggle ends up hiding it. Use `var content = $(this).text();` instead or find a plugin that will handle this better.

Comment: I changed the var content = $(this).text(). look at the Fiddle jsfiddle.net/Skdmk/1. It is working. But the <p> tag, line break is not working. Everything is coming inline without any break.

Comment: I end up using the expander plugin. http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Pluggin edition (new function):

```
$.fn.showHideParagraph = function(settings){
    var config = $.extend({},  $.fn.showHideParagraph.config, settings);
    $(this).on({click: function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('less')) {
            $this.removeClass('less').html(config.moreText);
        } else {
            $this.addClass('less').html(config.lessText);
        }

        $this.parent().siblings('p:not(:first)').animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'});
        return false;
    }
    }, '.morePLink');

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass("shortenedP")) return;

        $this.addClass("shortenedP");
        var paragraphs = $this.children('p');
        if (paragraphs.length > config.paragraphShowed) {
            paragraphs.not(":first").hide();

            paragraphs.first().append(" ...");
            var moreLess = '<span><a href="#" class="morePLink">'  + config.moreText + '</a></span>';
            $this.append(moreLess);
        }
    });
};

$.fn.showHideParagraph.config = {
    paragraphShowed: 1,
    ellipsesText: "...",
    moreText: 'more',
    lessText: 'less'
};
```

This supports p and you can configure the number of p showed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/544HN/